# Gstreamer stream h264 File

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to stream a h264 encoded movie file from a server to multiple clients at once by sending the RTP Stream to the broadcast address.

The solution I've got works but is very slow. Playing the video locally works fine.

Here's my Server:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=/home/zeroc8/Videos/bunny.mov \
! qtdemux ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.255 port=5000
```

This is the Client:

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=5000 \
caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"J01AHqkYGwe83gDUBAQG2wrXvfAQ\\,KN4JyA\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)786848209, clock-base=(uint)101553131, seqnum-base=(uint)64602" 
! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

Am I doing something bad here? Why is this so slow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just got the answer from the gstreamer mailing list.
In case anyone else is having the same problem, adding the gstrtpjitterbuffer element fixes it.

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=5000 \
caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"J01AHqkYGwe83gDUBAQG2wrXvfAQ\\,KN4JyA\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)786848209, clock-base=(uint)101553131, seqnum-base=(uint)64602" \ 
! gstrtpjitterbuffer latency=1000 
! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. does gstreamer open a gui for playing the video with the above command ?

Comment: Yes, it does. But you can also tell it to render into a separate drawing area by calling set_xwindow_id.